# What is the use of "pyro" in the naming of organic compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

Recently I asked a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43890/why-is-this-compound-named-resorcinol) on the naming of polyhydroxy phenols. One of them was [**pyro**gallol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrogallol) (1,2,3-Trihydroxybenzene) which is  synthesized from [gallic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallic_acid)  obtained from oak galls. (BEWARE- not a compound of gallium). 
[image]

But why "pyro"? Pyro is usen in naming inorganic acids like **pyro**sulfuric acid ($\ce{H2S2O7}$) or **pyro**phosphoric acid ($\ce{H4P2O7}$). It is also observed that the carboxylic acid derivative is gallic acid not pyrogallic acid and the hydroxy derivative is pyrogallol not gallol. Why is it so?

Comment: pyro- is not a part of systemtic naming, it is a prefix meaning 'fire' and is used with acids or salt preparable via route involving heating. Obviously, there is often more than one acid preparable such way, but only one usually ends with pyro- prefix. Thus, the prefix is not encourged.

Comment: @permeakra please consider submitting your comment as an answer, as this is precisely the reason.... The formation of that product comes from simply heating. The example in the question shows that nicely.  A link to the [IUPAC Gold Book](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04959.html) may be useful.

Comment: This question mainly applies to organic chemistry. For the use of the prefix “pyro-” in inorganic chemistry, see also the questions and answers [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40506/7951), [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43502/7951), and [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43826/7951).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, as @long and @permeakra stated, the name **pyro**gallol came from the fact that it is obtained by heating gallic acid. The [IUPAC goldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/P04959.html) clearly states that:-

> "pyro" is used as a prefix designating compounds formed by heating a compound,
>   usually with the elimination of water, carbon dioxide, or other simple
>   molecule, e.g. pyroglutamic acid from glutamic acid.

So as per rule, it is **pyro**gallol and not gallol.